# Play 2: Json request works locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I made a simple mobile (Android) app and web (Play 2.1.0) app. It's actually a whack-a-mole game on Android and you can POST your score on web app (and of course GET a list of top 10 scores).

So, GET top scores request and POST request both work flawlessly locally (on my computer). But when I push my app on Heroku, only GET top scores request work. The problem with POST request is, as I noticed, in the web api (Play2) controller that is receiving JSON (from Android). I guess it doesn't know how to parse Json from the request...

I use this way of handling Json request: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaJsonRequests

I modified my code to find a problem:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result newScore() {
    JsonNode json;
    try {
        json = request().body().asJson();
        String jsonString = json.toString();
        return ok(jsonString);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        return ok("PROBLEM");
    } 
}
```

The response on localhost is the json string I sent. The response on Heroku is catched exception with the String PROBLEM. It's a very weird problem, I don't know why it works ok on localhost, but not on heroku... Any ideas? :)

UPDATE (Android logcat):

```
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709): <!DOCTYPE html>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709): <html>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):     <head>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         <title>Error</title>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         <style>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             html, body, pre {
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 margin: 0;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 padding: 0;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 background: #ECECEC;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             }
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             h1 {
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 margin: 0;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 background: #A31012;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 padding: 20px 45px;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 color: #fff;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 border-bottom: 1px solid #690000;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 font-size: 28px;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             }
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             p#detail {
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 margin: 0;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 padding: 15px 45px;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 background: #F5A0A0;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 border-top: 4px solid #D36D6D;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 color: #730000;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 font-size: 14px;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):                 border-bottom: 1px solid #BA7A7A;
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             }
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         </style>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):     </head>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):     <body>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         <h1>Oops, an error occured</h1>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         <p id="detail">
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):             This exception has been logged with id <strong>6d9a6k11h</strong>.
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):         </p>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709):     </body>
02-08 00:01:09.140: I/SendResultService(18709): </html>
```

SOLUTION:
Ok, I solved a problem - it was in fact a problem in my Android code:

```
public void postData(String url,JSONObject obj) {
        HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
            //se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); // <-- PROBLEM
            httppost.setEntity(se); 

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.i(TAG, temp);
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {Log.e(TAG, "Client protocol ex");} 
        catch (IOException e) {Log.e(TAG, "io ex");}
    }
```

This code now works, I commented the problematic part: setting a BasicHeader to a string entity. This apparently wasn't problem for localhost, but it was for Heroku.

Comment: You might want to try calling `e1.getMessage()` and/or `e1.printStackTrace()` to give a hint as to what's causing the exception.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question with a e1.getMessage response. Still no clue...

Comment: I'll also paste heroku logs

Comment: Ok, I solved a problem but I can't post it, because this stupid StackOverflow doesn't allow me to. It was a problem in my Android code. I shouldn't setContentEncoding with BasicHeader to my StringEntity. So I commented out this line and it works now: se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));